# Zooper: How do I change the font in part of a Rich Text element?

Tags: app-widgets, customization

I want to make part of a Rich Text item in a Zooper widget a different font. For instance, making the hours on a clock Roboto Black, the colon Roboto, and the minutes Roboto Thin. However, I don't see anything in the BBCode samples that can do this. **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't in the [BBCode Reference](http://www.zooper.org/wp/android/zw/bbcode-reference), then it's probably not supported. I would suggest contacting the developer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be done in one Rich Text block. Try making three separate blocks for hours, colon and minutes which are text-aligned right, centre and left respectively and position them next to each other.